# Is there a free website to track domain IP and DNS changes?

Tags: domain-name-system, monitoring, ip, nameserver

I am looking for some free website to track the changes of IP and DNS of a domain name, I know a lot of websites that shows this information, but they only show the last IP and nameservers, I want to be able to see previous records if the domain name has any.

Does someone knows any website that provides this for free?

Answer (score 3):

[DNS History](http://dnshistory.org/) - The history of IP/DNS Records for domains.

Comment: Unfortunately "This site will shut down on the 10th July 2016 due to funding issues."

Comment: The records here are really stale

Answer (score 0):

whois.sc used to have this info for free, but it is a paid service now it seems: http://www.domaintools.com/research/hosting-history/